# Find device by port using devcon

Tags: c#, devcon

I've been looking everywhere, but cannot find that. 
How can I find device using devcon which is connected to (e.g) COM5?
I've tried devcon find

> devcon resurces =ports

which shows all devices, but I need only that one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Prolific PL2303 USB-Serial cable to test the following command

```
devcon find * | findstr /R (COM4)
```

If the cable is attached I got a result. If the cable is detached I got no result. To get a result even if the cable is unplugged, the following command does it.

```
devcon findall * | findstr /R (COM4)
```